# i used chloropeth library but the output is not colored

Tags: python, plotly

The code here is in python language for drawing map of haryana Districs for which I used geojsons file of Haryana.

```
import pandas as pd
import json 
import plotly.express as px
import numpy as np
import webbrowser
import plotly.io as pio
pio.renderers.default = 'browser'
haryana_districts = json.load(open("haryanas.geojsons",'r'))
haryana_districts['features'][2]
district_id_map = {}
for feature in haryana_districts['features']:
    feature['id'] = feature['properties']['ID_2']
    district_id_map[feature['properties']['NAME_2']] = feature['id']
df['populationScale'] = np.log10(df['population'])
df.head()
haryana_districts['features'][1]['properties']
fig = px.choropleth_mapbox(df,
                    locations='id',
                    geojson=haryana_districts,
                    color='populationScale',
                    hover_name='District',
                    hover_data=['population'],
                    mapbox_style="carto-positron",
                    color_continuous_scale=px.colors.diverging.BrBG,
                    color_continuous_midpoint=0)
fig.update_geos(fitbounds='locations', visible=False)
fig.show()
```

the output :
[Output Fig. is jut this blank screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YrKrz.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

- clearly I don't have access to your dataframe of population data, so have sourced from https://www.indiacensus.net/states/haryana
- additionally I have found **geojson** of districts in Harayana
- solution

  - there is no need to loop through and amend **geojson** use **locations** and **featureidkey** https://plotly.com/python/mapbox-county-choropleth/#indexing-by-geojson-properties

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import requests, io

# get population data
df = pd.read_html(
    io.StringIO(requests.get("https://www.indiacensus.net/states/haryana").text)
)[4].rename(
    columns={
        "S.No.": "id",
        "Estimated Population in 2022": "population",
        "District Name": "District",
    }
)
df["id"] = df["id"].astype(int)
df["populationScale"] = df["population"]

# pio.renderers.default = 'browser'
haryana_districts = requests.get(
    "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/shuklaneerajdev/IndiaStateTopojsonFiles/master/Haryana.geojson"
).json()

fig = px.choropleth_mapbox(
    df,
    locations="District",
    featureidkey="properties.Dist_Name",
    geojson=haryana_districts,
    color="populationScale",
    hover_name="District",
    hover_data=["population"],
    mapbox_style="carto-positron",
    color_continuous_scale=px.colors.diverging.BrBG,
    # color_continuous_midpoint=0,
).update_layout(
    mapbox={"center": {"lon": 76.93018408903318, "lat": 30.3276671165594}, "zoom": 5}
)
# fig.update_geos(fitbounds='locations', visible=False)
fig.show()
```

[image]